# sqlite3 - MAX() function does not return the maximum value of a column

Tags: sql, sqlite, max

Operating on a table of the following format:

```
name                      size        solution_length  solution_forks  backtravel_parallel  backtravel_perp  forks_to_dead  dead_overlap  weighted_dead_length
------------------------  ----------  ---------------  --------------  -------------------  ---------------  -------------  ------------  --------------------
AldousBroder_5_33342.txt  5           14               4               0                    0                4              26            444
AldousBroder_5_05916.txt  5           28               4               4                    0                4              28            728
```

This is how I would get the maximum value of a column.

```
sqlite> SELECT MAX(weighted_dead_length) FROM mazes_100k;

MAX(weighted_dead_length)
-------------------------
996
```

However, it doesn't seem to be the true maximum:

```
sqlite> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mazes_100k WHERE weighted_dead_length = 1000;

COUNT(*)
----------
15
```

Why is it that if I try counting the number of rows with the value of a column *higher* than what was returned by MAX() I still get some hits? It seems as if MAX() doesn't return the true maximum of a column.

By trial an error, using COUNT(), it seems that the true maximum is 1004 - how can I get MAX() to return that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are storing the value as a string rather than a number.  Convert the value to a number for the max:

```
SELECT MAX(weighted_dead_length + 0)
FROM mazes_100k;
```

or:

```
SELECT MAX(CASt(weighted_dead_length as INTEGER) )
FROM mazes_100k;
```

Comment: SQLite has an eccentric type system; no matter how you declare the column type you can insert data of a different type and SQLite will remember the type of the data and continue to treat it as that type when retrieved or compared.

Comment: Just for my understanding: if `weighted_dead_length` is a string, how does `WHERE weighted_dead_length = 1000` work?

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Why does it seem to work without the casting though? 996 was a plausible maximum value. Does it have something to do with how sqlite3 encodes strings?

Comment: @PhillipD - it might have something to do with [this](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#type_conversions_prior_to_comparison)?

Comment: this is a huge issue with sqlite - it doesn't see tabs and will accept untyped columns!